# Error 404 for internal url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I want this url rewrite?
This is my old URL:
    http://example.com/user.php?username=philip1

The new URL:
    http://example.com/user/philip1/

The .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^user\.php$ %{QUERY_STRING} [C]
RewriteRule ^username=(.*) /user/$1/? [R=301,L]
```

I get an object not found! or page doesn't exist this means am redirecting not rewriting.
PROBLEM:
I need internal rewrite use this Old URL:

```
http://example.com/user.php?username=philip1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
#Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#if the requsted filename is not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#then rewrite "/user/foo" to "/user.php?username=foo"
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ /user.php?username=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```